# Selenium Wait for element value to load

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, wait, specflow

I have looked at similar questions but I did not get the help I needed, I hope this is not a duplicate...

I would like selenium to wait for selenium to wait for a specific value. 
Or to wait while some javascript is running.

Here is an example:
Page object

```
class Converter
{
    private IWebDriver _webDriver;

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "tabin")]
    public IWebElement HexVaue { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "resulttxt")]
    public IWebElement DecimalValue { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#content > form > input[type='button']")]
    public IWebElement ConvertButton { get; set; }

    public Converter(IWebDriver webDriver)
    {
        _webDriver = webDriver;

        PageFactory.InitElements(_webDriver, this);
    }
```

Test code:

```
        _driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter");
        _converter = new Converter(_driver);
        _converter.HexVaue.SendKeys("100");
        _converter.ConvertButton.Click();
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        // Assert.AreEqual("256", _converter.DecimalValue.GetAttribute("value")); // Fails
        wait.Until(d => _converter.DecimalValue.GetAttribute("value").Equals("256"));
```

If I do a typical NUnit assert without this wait.Until, then the test fails. Is this the correct way for me to do this assertion in Selenium?

Thanks, Daryn

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your application.  Selenium operates extremely fast and sometimes will assert things before the application is ready.  I have often found that adding a `wait.until` is the easiest way to apply an assertion when you are unsure of the state of a specific element.

I find this especially useful when common performance tricks are to load the elements and then modify the DOM directly afterwards so that it appears to the user that the page is loaded even though the DOM gets modified after the initial screen load.